# To find the covariance given the joint probability density function

Tags: distributions, self-study, covariance, independence, joint-distribution

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynnsa.jpg):

> Suppose the pdf of $(X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4)$ is given by $$f(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=\begin{cases}\text{constant}&,\text{ if }x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2\le 1 \\ 0&,\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$
>
> Find the covariance between $X_1$ and $X_4$. Are $X_1$ and $X_4$ independent? Justify your answer.

I was solving some question papers and got stuck in this problem.

My problem:

I know how to find "marginal probabilities" from a joint probability density function and also know how to find the covariance and independence.

But I am getting stuck in the range part while integration.
While finding f(x1, x4) or f(x1) or during finding the covariance how do I integrate over the given range as I am not accustomed to handle such ranges as in here.(marked in red)

[image]

Please help me solve this.

Thank you.

Comment: First attempt the problem with two variables instead of four, so you can draw a picture of the range of integration.  Look at it closely to see whether there are any symmetries you can exploit to avoid computing integrals altogether.

Comment: You could try transforming to spherical coordinates for the integrals.

Comment: @Stubborn Although that works, it is by far the most difficult way to solve this problem.

Comment: @whuber I thought of drawing it graphically but I somehow cpuldnot make it..would it be a circle as x1^2+x4^2《 1-x2^2-x3^2 , here after drawing the circle how can I deal with the inequality ? Its not clear..Can you please help me?

Comment: @StubbornAtom  Can you please ellaborte how?

Comment: With two variables it's not a circle; it's a *disk* defined by $x_1^2+x_2^2\le1.$ The distribution is uniform on this disk. Thus, merely by *looking* at the diagram, you can read off the conditional distributions $X_2\mid X_1$ and you can see some obvious symmetries in the joint distribution of $(X_1,X_2),$ such as the reflections with respect to the coordinate axes. Without any further consideration, that answers both parts of the question. 
Now generalize to more variables. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/257859 or https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/135663 for examples.